# コマンドラインからRスクリプトに引数を渡すと意図しない引数に変更される

Tags: r

Windows7のコマンドラインから、引数を渡して、Rのスクリプトを実行すると、意図しない引数に変更されて実行される。

-- run.bat

```
Rscript --args "m10-19_6407_001" < run.R
pause
```

-- run.R

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
arg1 <- args[1]
print(args)
d <- read.csv(sprintf("%s.csv", arg1))
```

print(args)の結果
[1] "--file=m10-19_6407_001"

引数に「--file=」が自動で付加される。
期待した結果
"m10-19_6407_001"
実際の結果
"--file=m10-19_6407_001"

これは、commandArgs の使い方が間違っているのでしょうか。それとも、Windows用Rの仕様でしょうか。

お分かりになる方、教えてください。

Comment: `Rscript` を使う場合、`--args` オプションは必要ありません。`Rscript run.R "m10-19_6407_001"` とすればお望みの結果が得られます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決することができました。
マニュアルに、ご指摘のような記述が見つけられなかったので、助かりました。

ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントいただきました内容で解決することができました。

-- run.bat

```
Rscript run.R "m10-19_6407_001"
```

-- print(args)の結果

```
[1] "m10-19_6407_001"
```